# Grails 3.0.15 running embedded war / jar vs running in a container

Tags: java, groovy, grails-3.0, embedded-tomcat-8, embedded-container

Is running Grails in embedded mode (meaning the server is embedded  in the application) safe and ready for production?
Are there any known issues that shall prevent from using this mode?
Is embedded jar better than embedded war file?